# Pyspark save output into multiple formats

Tags: python, pyspark, save

Looking for saving pyspark output into parquet and csv together.

Right now I'm having this line for parquet:

```
self.func().coalesce(1).write.parquet(outputDir)
```

Is there a way of saving it together into multiple files? Or do I have to read the output file and save it as csv?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to run save twice..
df.coalesce(x).write.format("parquet").save(path1)
and df.coalesce(x).write.format("csv").save(path2)
where path1 is /data_parquet
and path2 is /data_csv.
You cannot save both format in same folder in one operation